# If $f(x)=f(\delta x), \delta>0$ a.e then $f$ is constant?

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $f\in L^{\infty}(0, \infty).$
For $\delta>0,$ $f(x)=f(\delta x)$ all most every where(a.e) on $(0, \infty).$

**My Question**: Can we expect $f$ is constant function on $(0, \infty)?$ If yes, how?

Comment: This property is to be positively $0$-homogeneous, there are many counter examples for $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ with $n \geq 2$, but for $n=1$ I don't know...

Comment: @Surb; thanks; do you mean one can expect in such thing in higher dimensions? (example ?)

Comment: $f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{\|(x,y)\|_2^2}$

Comment: For almostall $x$? For almost all $\delta$? For almost all delta for almost all $x$? For some $\delta$ for almost all $x$?

Comment: What is sure is that if we have $f(x)=f(\delta x)$ for every $\delta, x\in (0,\infty)$, then $f$ is constant. Since this imply $f(x) = f(x \cdot 1) = f(1)$ for every $x \in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen; For the given any $\delta>0,$ we have $f=f_{\delta}$ a.e; that is, $|A_{\delta}|=|\{x:f(x)\neq f_{\delta}(x)\}|=0.$

Comment: Let then $B = (0,\infty) \setminus A_\delta$, and $x,y \in B$, then $x,y>0$ and $f(x) = f\big((x/y)y\big) = f(y)$.

Comment: @Surb: This assumes $\delta = x/y$. The Problem is that each $\delta$ can have a different "exceptional set" $A_\delta$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks, I finally get it now :).

Comment: And $\delta=1$ is probably excluded ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard argument for problems like this:

If you have a (compactly supported, continuous) function $g \in L^1((0,\infty))$, consider the convolution (calculated w.r.t. the Haar measure on $(0,\infty)$)

$$
(f \ast g)(x)= \int_0^\infty f(x/y) g(y) \,dy/y.  
$$

The convolution is defined for **every** $x$ because of $f \in L^\infty$.

Now an easy calculation using the change of variables formula yields

$$
(f \ast g)(\delta x) = (f \ast g)(x)
$$
for **all** $\delta , x >0$.

This will allow you to conclude that $f \ast g $ is constant.

Now choosing $g = g_\varepsilon$ as a suitable approximation of unity, you get $f \ast g_\epsilon \to f$ pointwise a.e. (at every Lebesgue point of $f$). This implies that $f$ is constant a.e.

EDIT: If you know that every (almost everywhere) translation invariant function over the reals is (almost everywhere) constant, you could also consider $x \mapsto f(\exp(x))$.

This also allows you to calculate the convolution over the reals instead of over $(0,\infty)$.